# How to Vectorize the finite-difference method using NumPy array arithmetic Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to use Numpy arithmetic to vectorize the finite-difference method on a numpy array of values (excluding edge values). Should take the average of surrounding values (top, bottom, left, right) to calculate it.

For example, should be able to take a numpy array like:

```
u = np.array([[100., 100., 100., 100., 100.],
             [100.,  0.,    0.,   0.,  100.],
             [100.,  0.,    0.,   0., 100.],
             [100.,  0.,    0.,   0., 100.],
             [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.]])
```

And return:

```
[[100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]
[100.  50.  25.  50. 100.]
[100.  25.   0.  25. 100.]
[100.  50.  25.  50. 100.]
[100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]]
```

Have already got it to work with for-loops, but it's rather inefficient. Array sizes and values can vary.

So far I have been trying to use subarrays to vectorize the solution, but haven't been able to figure out to get it to work:

```
import numpy as np

#example array
x = np.array([[100.,   2.,   3.,   7., 100.],
              [100.,   5.,   3.,   7., 100.],
              [100.,   3.,   6.,   3., 100.],
              [50.,   4.,   5.,   2., 100.],
              [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.]])

lbarrier = (np.size(x, 1))+1
rbarrier = (np.size(x, 1))-1
bbarrier = (np.size(x, 0))-1




#inner vals
itops = x[0:bbarrier][1:rbarrier][0][1:rbarrier]
ibot = x[0:bbarrier][1:rbarrier][-1][1:rbarrier]
ileft = x[1:bbarrier,1]
iright = x[1:bbarrier,-2]



#edge vals
etops = np.array(x[0:][0:][0][1:-1])
ebot = np.array(x[0:][0:][-1][1:-1])
eleft = np.array(x[1:bbarrier, 0])
eright = np.array(x[1:bbarrier, -1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is common in image processing.  You are "convolving" a matrix with a "kernel".  `scipy` has `ndimage` that does this.  It looks like you have padded your inner matrix with the value of 100 for the edge.  So this works for the inner portion:

```
In [49]: from scipy import ndimage                                              

In [50]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [51]: k                                                                      
Out[51]: 
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.25],
       [0.  , 0.25, 0.  ]])

In [52]: u = np.zeros((3,3))                                                    

In [53]: ndimage.convolve(u, k, mode='constant', cval=100.0)                    
Out[53]: 
array([[50., 25., 50.],
       [25.,  0., 25.],
       [50., 25., 50.]])

In [54]:
```

You may need to tinker with the above to get what you want, but I think this is the path you want.

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track (I was originally screwing around with `np.pad`), but I felt it didn't fully answer the question (in particular, producing the full expected output). Hope you don't mind that I built on it in my answer.

Comment: @jeff-h Is there a way to make a vectorized solution that's about 8x more efficient? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use `scipy.signal.convolve`:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve

mask = [[0, 1, 0], 
        [1, 0, 1], 
        [0, 1, 0]]

convolved = convolve(u, mask, mode='valid') / np.sum(mask)
```

`mask` is a representation of which source elements, in relation to an element in the result, are combined to give that element. This therefore gives you a `(3, 3)` array containing the center of your expected output (`mode='valid'` is passed to ignore edges).

We can then put this back into a copy of the original:

```
result = u.copy()
result[1:-1, 1:-1] = convolved

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]
 [100.  50.  25.  50. 100.]
 [100.  25.   0.  25. 100.]
 [100.  50.  25.  50. 100.]
 [100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it works well. However, the main issue is that it's not efficient enough to meet my needs, and therefore needs to be solved with vectorization. Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: @Charlieglider Why do you say that it's not vectorised?

Comment: Just as a disclaimer, I'm not very familiar with vectorization and it's applications (main reason I'm asking :) ), so I assumed that your solution wasn't vectorized based on it's efficiency. I'm looking for a vectorized solution that's about 8 times faster. Would appreciate any help. Thanks